# mysql hosted DB, jdbc after a while the application freezes

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, innodb

I run a java programm and try to use it with a hosted DB, I run the Vserver ubuntu 12.04 with Mysql myself, full root-access.

I changed the `my.cnf` to have more resources.
When I start the application it is fast, hardly any difference to a local database.

My problem is that after a while of inactivity the program freezes probably because the connection dropped.
There is no entry in any errorlog. If I kill the application and restart it, it is working again, nothing else but kill works, it is a linuxPC.

I used `?autoReconnect=true` but I am not sure this is correct, the tables are innodb.

Does anyone have an idea how to avoid the connection to drop or how to make sure a reconnection is made?

**PS** [17.12.2015]
`?autoReconnect=true` was removed

today I got some details after a long wait

```
com.openbravo.basic.BasicException: 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 2.435.471 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 959.832 milliseconds ago.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: 
Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 2.435.471 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 959.832 milliseconds ago.

java.net.SocketException:
```

Is this what happens when `wait_timeout` is too short?
After the "error" the program worked again!

Comment: could you tell more about the activity of your java program? how the connection is established?

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks specific info, but I guess what is happen. MySQL Server has a parameter called `wait_timeout` (*See [official doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout)*).

When you have a `connection` that exceed that timeout, MySQL will close it, and if you don't manage SQLExceptions properly, your application will have problems.

You can try to increase `wait_timeout` or review your connection code to manage exceptions, but both are workarounds.

I wouldn't recommend you to relay on `autoReconnect` as an *alternative for any problem*, instead it would be better to encapsulate connection management into business logic in order to manage open/close connection every time you need. Maybe connection pooling can help you.

I mean, when you call a business method from you UI (*it doesn't mind if it is web, ws, desktop or whatever*) you have to manage open connection and start transaction, (*and other cross cutting concerns as authorization, audit, log, ...*). During all businesses logic, control possible exceptions, commit or rollback and free resources.

If you post some code, you will get more specific answers.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the link. The application is not made by me, it is a Java appilcation that runs fine on a localhost but I would like to use a hosted DB for reasons of mobility. I will start and experiment with the value for wait_timeout.

Answer (score 1):

autoReconnect is dangerous for InnoDB.  When the connection is lost in the middle of a transaction the previous actions in the transaction are rolled back.  But the code proceeds to run as if the transaction continues.  This can lead to subsequent writes not being consistent with the rolled back data.

You would be better off recognizing the lost connection and restarting the transaction.